# How can I move the second window of a Process into a panel?

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to place the output of a Windows forms application into a Panel (panel2) within another application. This is my code so far:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr Handle, int x, int y, int w, int h, bool repaint);

pcproc = Process.Start(@"C:\\Program Files (x86)\Application\app.exe");
pcproc.WaitForInputIdle();
SetParent(pcproc.MainWindowHandle, panel2.Handle);
MoveWindow(pcproc.MainWindowHandle, panel2.Location.X, panel2.Location.Y, panel2.Width, panel2.Height,true);
```

Now unfortunately the application launches 2 windows (both do not have a Window title, and I can't change that unfortunately), the 2nd of which that gets launched, is the one I would like to place in the panel. The above code only places the 1st window in the panel, which I don't want. So how can I move the 2nd window that is launched, into the panel as well?

Comment: Are all applications here your own, and modifiable? If not, you're going down a very dark path and it's probably not going to work out well. Programs tend to be written to assume that their own top-level windows will remain top-level, and not suddenly have another window announce that they're it's parent.

Comment: See [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx) by Raymond Chen. Choice quote: "Yes, it is technically legal.

It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws."

Comment: I'm aware of the risks, but I would still like to go ahead and do this.